# How do you write a continuous arpeggio in sheet music?

Tags: notation, sheet-music, arpeggios

How would you write an arpeggio that never stops the notes that are played . . . they just keep on ringing. E.g, in the example below, when the E is played in measure 1 beat 1, it continues ringing all the way up to when it is struck again, and then it rings some more. This also happens with every other note.

```
1  +  2  +  3  +  4  +  1  +  2  +  3  +  4  +
E  B  F# G     B  F# G  E  B  F# G     B  F# G
```

I'm sure it's been done before, seeing that guitars usually play arpeggios in this way.

Comment: This could vary depending on the instrument. Often for the classical guitar and even other guitars, this would be the default interpretation with no special notation needed.

Comment: Is this common in harp strums or piano rolled chords? I heard that there are right hand and left hand notation signs, and another that tells you whether the chords are to be rolled upward or downward.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Usually this is notated with the comment  "let ring" above or below the staff; optionally you can include a dashed line (similar to an 8va line) that indicates the span of music where it should be played this way.

Here's a good [example](http://www.scribd.com/doc/20998617/Marriage-D-Amour-FOR-GUITAR)

Comment: Perfect! Just wondering, what would be expected if you place a rest in there somewhere?

Comment: A rest would indicate silencing the strings.  Note that you could write a rest for the bass and/or treble lines independently.